# MySQL 5.5.49 returns errors if UNION and CREATE TABLE co-exists

Tags: mysql, union

In mysql  Distrib 5.5.49, there are 2 tables, and we are trying to recycle data (copy all the columns except the ID column) when the data contents with different IDs are the same.

Please see the fiddle for example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91c1cf/5

The question is the following query run perfectly fine when run separately:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Score FROM MAIN

UNION

SELECT d.New_Id AS Id, c.Name, c.Score FROM MAIN c
RIGHT JOIN SUB d

ON c.Id = d.Id
```

However, when it combines with CREATE TABLE command, an error message keeps popping out:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST (

SELECT Id, Name, Score FROM MAIN

UNION

SELECT d.New_Id AS Id, c.Name, c.Score FROM MAIN c
RIGHT JOIN SUB d

ON c.Id = d.Id );
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
```

It turns out that MySQL might not support UNION together with CREATE TABLE?  The user manual here is not very clear.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Could any guru enlighten?

Comment: This should work if the syntax is correct - `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST AS SELECT......` Add an `AS` keyword, and remove the surrounding `()`.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you should add it as an answer. It does work in fact.

Comment: Oh my!!! "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST AS SELECT......" does work!!!  Learning something!